# Doing a for loop on bunch of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 1002 tuples in which there are an index and an 11 columns data. I would like to write a for loop to make each of those columns one numpy array based on changing the column "T". In the sense that each of theses data frames becomes stored in a separated data frame.

```
index       "T"    "A"        "B"       "C"       "D"        "X"      "Y"  
7991       7.0  0.473794  0.455378  0.473734  0.496816  0.006206  0.404610   
7992       7.0  0.473794  0.455378  0.473734  0.496816  0.007155  0.398412   
7994       7.0  0.473794  0.455378  0.473734  0.496816  0.009044  0.384093   
7996       7.0  0.473794  0.455378  0.473734  0.496816  0.010910  0.365135   
7997       7.0  0.473794  0.455378  0.473734  0.496816  0.011825  0.352924
```

I have done an example and I want to do for the whole of my dataset

```
df_train_array_0 = np.array(df_train_list[0][1])
```

I have done once but I got an error: `list indices must be integers or slices, not float`

```
for index in df_train_list[1]:
    df_train_array = np.array(df_train_list["T"][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's because you calling "T", that is a float number, you should try:

```
for index in df_train_list:
    df_train_array = np.array(df_train_list["T"][1])
```

Comment: I have banned asking any questions, could you please upvote me to release the ban?